# WebAssembly in distributed ubiquitous computing

Tags: webassembly

I have a (hypothetical) question about WebAssembly.
So I'm building a distributed computing system in Java with mobile bytecode as a feature. I was wondering if WASM can be used to transport C/C++ code from one machine (say x86) to another (say ARM) and execute on that node?

I understand that WASM doesn't currently provide Java support but plans to in future and one can see how this becomes beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's JVM is a virtual machine that executes bytecode. WebAssembly is a similar concept, a bytecode, that is executed by a virtual machine . Both virtual machines support multiple languages - I'd say it stands to reason you could use WebAssembly for your distributed computing applications.

Comment: Web assembly it is NOT virtual machine, it is bytecode itself, that executes in browser provided virtual machine

Comment: So I assume at this time and in the future the JVM will outperform the WasmVM?